# The macOS system must be configured so that the su command requires smart card authentication

Tags: mojave, login

I am following some hardening guide and in the specific I am doing the **AOSX-14-003051** **V-95983**
from the following website: https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/apple_os_x_1014_mojave_security_technical_implementation_guide

You can open the website and search for the keywords **AOSX-14-003051** or you can search for the keywords **V-95983**

If you read the **Fix Text Column** and the **Check Content Column** I am not sure why they are telling me to do a back up of the `su` file and modify the `login` file?

Should it be: back up of the `login` file and then modify the `login` file?

Or I am missing something?

In case you do not want to visit the website, here below what they are asking to do:

Make a backup of the PAM SU settings using the following command:

```
cp /etc/pam.d/su /etc/pam.d/su_backup_`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M"`
```

Replace the contents of "/etc/pam.d/login" with the following:

```
# su: auth account session
auth sufficient pam_smartcard.so 
#auth required pam_opendirectory.so
auth required pam_deny.so 
account required pam_permit.so
password required pam_deny.so
session required pam_permit.so
```

To verify that the "su" command has been configured to require smart card authentication, run the following command:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/su | grep -i pam_smartcard.so
```

If the text that returns does not include the line, "auth sufficient pam_smartcard.so" at the TOP of the listing, this is a finding.